Generalizing the relative homology group of the solid torus relative to the hollow torus
In Hatcher's Algebraic Topology textbook, we are given some tools to calculate relative homology groups, the prime example of which, as I have seen, are finding the relative homology group of the solid torus relative to the hollow torus (see here and here). I would like to generalize the result to an arbitrary topological space $X$.
More precisely, If $D^2$ denotes the $2$-dimensional disk, I would like to express the relative homology groups $H_i(X \times D^2, X \times \partial D^2)$ in terms of homology groups of $X$.
Here is my work so far:
We know that $H_i(X \times \partial D^2) \cong H_i(X) \oplus H_{i-1}(X)$ for all $i$ (by convention, $H_{-1}(X) := 0$). Thus, from the short exact sequence $0 \to \partial X \times D^2 \hookrightarrow X \times D^2 \to (X \times D^2) / (X \times \partial D^2) \to 0$, we get the following long exact sequence
$$
\cdots \to H_i(X \times \partial D^2) \cong H_i(X) \oplus H_{i-1}(X) \to H_i(X \times D^2) \cong H_i(X) \to H_i(X \times D^2, X \times \partial D^2) \xrightarrow{\partial} H_{i-1}(X \times \partial D^2) \cong H_{i-1}(X) \oplus H_{i-2}(X) \to \cdots.
$$
The difficulty I am having is, since we don't have nice $H_i($something$) = 0$ as we have in some problems, it's difficult to express $H_i(X \times D^2, X \times \partial D^2)$ in terms of $H_j(X)$ in this case. As $H_i$ and $\tilde{H_i}$ doesn't differ so much (and in fact are the same for relative homology groups), considering the reduced homology groups also didn't lead to much insight either.
I also was thinking of applying the relative homological version of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, but I ran into a similar problem of having none of the factors I desired in a nice form.

Do you have access to the (relative) Kunneth Theorem? https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/Kunneth.pdf

When this happens, unfortunately you have to dig into at least one of the induced maps or use fancy technology like a Künneth theorem.
Consider the map $i:X\times \partial D^2\hookrightarrow X\times D^2$. In homology, $i_*:H_i(X\times \partial D^2)\rightarrow H_i(X\times D^2)$ is basically an isomorphism on the homology of $X$ and sends the cycles in $S^1$ to zero since they all become boundaries under $i$. The isomorphism $H_i(X\times S^1)\cong H_i(X)\oplus H_{i-1}(X)$ tells you that the cycles in $X\times S^1$ come from pairing the cycles in $X$ with those in $S^1$. So we can say that $\ker(i_*)\cong H_{i-1}(X)$ and $\text{im}(i_*)\cong H_i(X)$. Essentially your $i_*$ is a projection map.
Let's call the next map $q_*$. We know that $\text{ker}(q_*) = \text{im}(i_*)\cong H_{i}(X)$. Also from $H_i(X\times D^2, X\times S^1)\xrightarrow{\partial} H_{i-1}(X\times \partial D^2)\xrightarrow{i_*}H_{i-1}(X)$ we get that $\text{im}(\partial) \cong H_{i-2}(X)$. So we can break the long exact sequence into shorter pieces.
$0\rightarrow \text{coker}(i_*)\xrightarrow{q_*}H_i(X\times D^2,X\times \partial D^2)\xrightarrow{\partial}\text{im}(\partial) \rightarrow 0$.
But $\text{coker}(i_*) = H_i(X)/\text{im}(i_*) = 0$, so $\partial$ is actually an isomorphism (in this SES).
Alternatively, you can try to use the relative Kunneth Formula, which I think should say something like
$$H_i(X\times D^2,X\times S^1)\cong \bigoplus_{p+q = i}H_p(X)\otimes H_q(D^2,S^1)\oplus \bigoplus_{p+q=i} \text{Tor}(H_p(X),H_q(D^2,S^1))$$
The $H_q$ term is $\mathbb{Z}$ only when $q=2$, and thus the $\text{Tor}$ term contributes nothing and we have a single term when $p = i-2$. But you should assume I'm lying and check this out more carefully for yourself.
